# Parse error when parsing manifest. Discontinuing installation

Tags: android, apk, android-app-signing

I have an apk that installs fine on all my devices except on an old Samsung Galaxy J5 (and on a Huawei Y3).

I had copy the APK on the device via USB and try to install it with the "my files" app. The log is as follows:

```
02-08 11:36:56.226 1647-1674/? D/ActivityManager:  Launching com.google.android.packageinstaller, updated priority
02-08 11:36:56.226 1647-1647/? D/GameManagerService: NotifyRunnable. pkg: com.google.android.packageinstaller, type: 4, isMinimized: false, isTunableApp: false
02-08 11:36:56.226 1647-1647/? D/GameManagerService: unexpected mPrevNotiType: -1
02-08 11:36:56.246 1647-1836/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:843 com.android.server.policy.PhoneWindowManager.notifyToSSRM:9071 com.android.server.policy.PhoneWindowManager.access$2100:330 com.android.server.policy.PhoneWindowManager$PolicyHandler.handleMessage:1268 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage:102 
02-08 11:36:56.246 19954-19954/? W/PackageInstaller: Parse error when parsing manifest. Discontinuing installation
```

Did anybody come across something like that as well?
I´ve checked the option that I can install APK from unknown sources so that can´t be the problem. And I´ve tried to install it from SD-card or internal memory with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody comes around the same problem. I was able to fix it by not using the signing function in Androidstudio but by manually using jarsigner and zipalign from java and the android-sdk-tools.